# Heat equation inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

There is an inequality that tells us that for some sufficiently smooth $f$ satisfying  $(\partial_t - \Delta )f \le  - \delta f^2 +K$ for $\delta,K >0$ that $f$ is bounded by some constant. Unfortunatey, I forgot the name and exact statement of this inequality and was wondering if anybody here knows a reference?

Comment: Looks like the subsolution estimate for the heat equation. Any PDE book should have it. Observe that you may estimate the right hand side above by $K$ just be dropping the negative term. This means $f$ is a subsolution for the heat equation with a constant right hand side. Then you can use Moser iteration to show that $f$ is locally bounded. I don't know if there is any well-established name for the estimate, though.